# Unable to get the data in Azure ML from SQL Server

Tags: azure, azure-pipelines

My question ,is there a way to retrieve the data from a SQL Server into an Azure ML pipeline or into the datastore ?

I am currently have a pipeline in Azure machine learning that's taking in data from the datastore and then training a model on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to Azure ML studio and click on Data -> Datastore and provide required details.

[image]

*Next create dataset, Set the name and type for your data asset -> Query the database.*
[image]

*Go to Designer, Visualize the data in workflow*

[image]

For more information **refer** this [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LMY2NRQR4uE&t=699s).